# Does Kinesis support HTTP (not HTTPS)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis

Now I try out Kinesis REST API with HTTPS and it's work fine. But I want to build it with only HTTP, not HTTPS. Does Kinesis support HTTP without SSL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it doesn't.  According to the Regions and Endpoints documentation  the Kinesis endpoints only support HTTPS.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#ak_region

If you are in a situation where you need to communicate with an API that only supports HTTPS but you are, for some significant reason, constrained to HTTP only, you might find that you could use a proxy that can accept unencrypted connections and originate encrypted connections to the final endpoint.  On some of my legacy systems, I have accomplished this with HAProxy 1.5 or higher (previous versions do not have built-in openssl integration)... or Stunnel4, which I used before HAProxy 1.5 was released.  Apparently there is now an Stunnel "5."

Of course, this is only viable if the network between the legacy system and your SSL client offloading is trusted.